# Missing CDN link for ui-grid

Tags: ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

Having had a good Google, I can't seem to find a CDN link for [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info) ... is there a reason it's not on a CDN?

**Edit:** [Added to CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-grid) Sept. 2015

Comment: <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">

Comment: Thanks, but that's not a CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the latest stable version here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-grid

Answer (score 6):

Yes, because UI-Grid (as of this writing) is still pre-release. Once it's ready for release we'll look at automating submission to something like cdnjs.

In the meantime you can use rawgit.com's cdn links:

```
//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-rc.20/ui-grid.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-rc.20/ui-grid.min.css
```

Just replace the release tag with the most recent RC.